# How to filter URLS in chrome extension that do not start with http or https

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension

I am learning how to write Chrome extensions, and am doing so because of a tool I need for testing in our local enviornment. I am trying to make the manifest file's section where you tell it what URLs to run against, but our testing enviornment urls are not working with it. We map the domains for example like this:

> Example.com  instead of http://example.com

Though, when I place this in my manifest settings, it gives me an error for invalid url without a

Manifest code here:

```
 {
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "K Domain Cleaner",
  "version": "0.1",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "kc-domaincleaner-1.0.js"]
    }
  ]  
}
```

When I try to set matches property like so:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "K Domain Cleaner",
  "version": "0.1",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["Dev3.com"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "kc-domaincleaner-1.0.js"]
    }
  ]  
}
```

I get the following error:

> Failed to load extension from: ~\Desktop\Chrome Extensions
>   Invalid value for 'content_scripts[0].matches[0]': Missing scheme separator

So It will not only run under our testing domains. Why can I not use a prefix of http://, and is there a way around this. http://Dev3.com is totally different then Dev3.com.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense because without a transport protocol (be it `http` or anything else) the **site** can't be reached (obviously). And a "site" isn't your network "domain". Also, have you read the documentation on [match patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns)?

Comment: I know what http protocol and how sites are reached. I have been a web applications developer for 9 years, and started with NASA Research, then HP, and on skipping college. I just started at this company and think they do so for reasons similar to  url canonicalization. The site test environments do not load if you prefix it with http, or https. (Yes I know canonicalization is based on www prefixes, but the concept is the same. Cataloging, etc.

Comment: I did read the documentation before posting, but was hoping there was some way around it, or I overlooked something. I cannot stand pompas responses to questions from community users. Yes, some questions may seem ridiculous to some, and not to others. Its relative. The purpose of this site and community is to spread knowledge, and progress, not intellectual classes or social status. So a simple response would of been fine, and the condescending attitude really isn't necessary, nor helpful.    So why even post it.

Comment: Because it's you who must indicate you know all that in your question. In almost all cases the lack of something in the question means the lack of effort or knowledge. Especially if the task is contradicting the documented and general state of things.

Comment: As for your question, you can check what protocol is actually used by opening the developer tools (F12 key), the Network panel, then reload the page and examine the requests.

Comment: Ah, and by the way I didn't *mean* to be condescending, so I'm sorry for that. In the future I'll be more careful with my wording. I can delete all my comments here once you read this.

Answer (score 2):

This *is* an invalid URL.

A URL [by definition *must* contain the scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.1). Without it, it can be interpreted as an address, but not as *what* (and *how*) you want to *access* at that address.

If you're entering a domain name without a scheme in the address bar, it's assumed to be `http:` by default, just like not entering a port assumes some default (that depends on the scheme).

In that context "http://Dev3.com is totally different then Dev3.com" makes no sense, though it is strictly true: one is a valid URL, and another is just a string (that happens to be a valid domain name).

Do note: Chrome simply hides `http://` from the address bar, but it's implicitly there. That may be the source of your confusion. Rest assured that `http://example.com` will cover an address that's displayed in the address bar as `example.com`.

As wOxxOm mentions, you should [take a look at the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) as well.

Comment: Why is it that if i type Dev3.com, it hits the environment internally though, but not when i type https://Dev3.com?  And yes to your answer about invalid url,  read that in the api.

Comment: Your link in the comment is to `https://Dev3.com`, not `http:`. For that, you can use match pattern `*://Dev3.com` to cover both http and https

Comment: Do note though, specifying a path is mandatory. So `*://Dev3.com/*`